# Instability with dual-booting Win7 + Ubuntu - Would VirtualBox be more stable?

Tags: dual-boot

I want to use Ubuntu for everything except Video editing in TMPGEnc, for which I need Windows, and possibly some other aps like Premiere. So far my attempt at dual-booting has produced a lot of errors and software crashes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on your hardware really and how much you can afford to allocate to your vm. Honestly, if your doing resource intensive things and you want both os's then I would try to work through the issues with the dual booting. Also consider a solid state drive if your worried about booting between os's. I do it now and it's not to bad. It can be a hassle sometimes though.

Comment: AricC how does that work? A separate hard drive?

Comment: Here is a link to how to dual boot windows 7. http://lifehacker.com/5403100/dual-boot-windows-7-and-ubuntu-in-perfect-harmony . It's a little dated but it will get the job done. Use whatever version of Ubuntu you want, but I would go for the latest lts(long term support)

Answer (score 0):

Virtual Box works surprisingly well. My son uses FL Studio, and it works without mayor problems. The workflow is much better if you dont have to reboot every time you want check your emails. 
But I think for rendering things you might need also a native Windows install. Try it out, if VB is fast enough for your needs, you can assign more processor.

Comment: thank you.  I am so happy it's possible for Ubuntu to host it for the few tasks I need it for.